# Delete Call log from call log list in blackberry os 7.1 programmatically

Tags: blackberry

I want to delete a call log from a call log list in Blackberry 7.1 OS. I am using this approach to delete recent call log:

```
PhoneLogs phn = PhoneLogs.getInstance();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           phn.deleteCall(0,PhoneLogs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS);

        }
    }).start();
```

This works well on 4.7 OS, but it didn't works on 7.1 OS. I want to know how to delete a call log in OS 7.1?

Comment: What context is this being run in?  Are you starting this from a listener which is probably running in the Phone Context, or in your own application after switching context (using a global event perhaps)?

Comment: Hi peter i am running this code from a listener and this is running in the Phone Context i am not using GlobalEvents.

Comment: I would try switching to your own Application, i.e. use a Global Event.  This is a similar problem that should provide some help with this: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Screen-not-opening-when-i-am-deleting-one-call-log/td-p/2770095

Comment: Hi i found some progress regarding that issue, when a call log is added to call log list  and by clicking on menu button go to view history option you can view same call log here, when i apply above delete code the call log which appears in view history deleted the call log in call log list not deleted in os 7.1